# White arrow on GitHub folder

Tags: git, github, push

I have a folder inside a repository that has a white arrow on it.

Through google searches, I found that a solution to this was deleting the .git folder inside the subfolder that has a white arrow on it. I did this, ran git add, git commit, and git push, but the subfolder still has a white arrow on it. How do I get rid of this so that the folder works properly?

[image: Screenshot of white arrow]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Arrow stands for a link to something, so it is probably either a submodule or a symlink.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: I just want it to act as a normal folder. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you have provided is a symlink, that is a link to another file, probably not even in the repository. If you click on it, it should just show you the path that it links to. That can be something within your repo, or something arbitrary that does not exist.

If you want it to actually contain the files that it contains, figure out what it points to, then delete the symlink and copy the linked folder to that position.

See [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/287014/how-to-create-and-use-symbolic-links-aka-symlinks-on-linux/) for an introduction to what symlinks are.

---

**Please not that it is NOT a "pointer to another repo"**, like @jessehouwing suggested. Those are called subrepositories or submodules and look like this, showing a pointed-to commit:

[image: screenshot of a subrepo in github]

---

[source repo of the screenshot](https://github.com/clawpack/tidal-examples) (arbitrary choice)